# How to Perform Join in HQL

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables Course, and Subject both are in many to many relationship.

The Third table is **Course_Subject**.

I have to perform  `join` to fetch all Courses.

I tried to join the Tables like:

```
hqlQuery="FROM Course c inner join fetch  c.Course_Subject as  s where c.id=s.courseId and s.subjectId=:subjectId";
```

but it is showing `NullpointerException`.

Please suggest me.

Comment: @ but how to improve it??

Answer (score 3):

HQL queries use entities and their association. Never tables and their columns. And it knows on which tables and columns entities are linked together, so you don't need to repeat it in the join query. To fetch all the courses having a given subject, you just need

```
select c from Course c
inner join c.subjects s
where s.id = :subjectId
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
hqlQuery="select c.field1,c.field2,s.field1 from Course c 
         inner join c.course_subject as s";
```

But why did you need this ? by default you can get subjects for a course by mapping like

```
cource.getSubjects();
```

Comment: that you can get using mapping in subject class. `subject.getCourses();`

Comment: when I setting the Course Class Mapping to Subject Class it showing error like:-> A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: DAL.Learn.Course@2f730b9a -> DAL.Common.Subject@31beefdc -> DAL.Learn.Course@2f730b9a what is this ??

Comment: seems cyclic reference. I dont have any idea.